# Error with output clause in insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm a little stumped as to why my output clause won't work.  Am I doing something silly?  I keep getting the error, " Incorrect syntax near 'output'."

```
--Create the table to insert into, with identity
create table #testtab(
    businessno int identity(1,1),
    businessname varchar(100), 
    businessref varchar(50), 
    moduser varchar(10), 
    moddate datetime, 
    modtype char(1)
);

--Insert statement with output to capture inserted id numbers
insert into #testtab (businessname, businessref, moduser, moddate, modtype) 
output inserted.businessno,inserted.businessref
values('asd','asd','asd',getdate(),'x');
```

This is in 2008R2.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Yeah.  I was being a numpty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah.... my bad.  I was actually connected to a SQL 2000 instance from SSMS.  Woops.  Doesn't look like 2000 supports output.  *Sigh*

Comment: Just to confirm, this worked when I ran it in an actual SQL 2008 instance.

Comment: I want to avoid using loops or cursors, so I guess a trigger is my next best bet.

Comment: Yes, the `OUTPUT` clause was a new feature in SQL Server **2005**